# Why does empty() behave differently for variable and array offset?

Tags: php

I have snippet of code which behaviour I do not understand. TRUE value is giving different result when passed to `empty()` in different copies of variable.

`var_dump($this->controller->type['Company']['is_active']); // bool(true)`

property *`$controller`* is object with *`$type`* property which is multi array. value of `is_active` is *`bool(true)`*

What should be the result of `empty()`?

`var_dump(!empty($this->controller->type['Company']['is_active'])); //false`

ok, let's create a copy

`$temp = $this->controller->type['Company']['is_active'];
var_dump(!empty($temp)); //true`

hmmm different result?

`var_dump($this->controller->type['Company']['is_active'] === $temp);//true`

what about casting?

`var_dump(!empty((int)$this->controller->type['Company']['is_active'])); //true`

Could someone explain this behaviour please?

Comment: Thing is, if `$this->controller->type['Company']['is_active']` is in fact `bool(true)` then `var_dump(!empty($this->controller->type['Company']['is_active']));` should in fact be `bool(true)`. Since you're essentially doing `var_dump(!empty(true));` which is in fact `bool(true)`. Something is fishy here...

Comment: Cannot confirm your issue. https://3v4l.org/NH3FN

Comment: debugging: `var_dump($this->controller->type['Company']['is_active'], $temp);` so we can see what is really in them.

Comment: @Andrew thats the point, we expect it to be `true` but it is `false`. is there some possibility that `is_active` is *something* else what acts like `true` when dumping? or maybe passing by reference is problem

Answer (score 0):

Please refere php manual, http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

> Returns FALSE if var exists and has a non-empty, non-zero value.
>   Otherwise returns TRUE.
>
> Note that empty works with pass by variable not with pass by value.

The following things are considered to be empty:

- `""` (an empty string)
- `0` (0 as an integer)
- `0.0` (0 as a float)
- `"0"` (0 as a string)
- `NULL`
- `FALSE`
- `array()` (an empty array)
- `$var;` (a variable declared, but without a value)